# Getting an asp radiobuttonlist to fire its TextChanged event via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, textchanged

I dont get why i cant get the TextChanged event to fire on postback after changing its values
with jquery.

What i mean is that i have an asp radiobuttionlist on my webpage. and it seems it has a TextChanged event for radiobuttons.

Lets say My radiobutton is called rblTest like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblTest" ClientIDMode="Static" 
  OnTextChanged="rblTest_TextChanged"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and the "code behind" is setup like this:

```
protected void rblTest_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Yay it fired TextChanged Event");
}
```

well pretty simple test, but i actually want it to fire before putting some code in it.

---

But then i try to actually change the text of some of the radiobutton items like this:

```
        $('#rblTest_0').val("inputchanged");
        $("label[for='rblTest_0']").html("thislabelisalsochanged");
```

And that works (visually) - i can see the values changing at the first item on my radiobuttonlist and all works fine.

But then when a postback is made it does not fire the TextChanged event... no matter what i do.

---

so is it not possible to make it fire the TextChanged event on a radiobuttonlist with jquery/javascript?

if i did the same with a textbox this would work.

Hope u guys can explain what im doing wrong or/and why this isnt possible!

NOTE: just tried to make it print out text after a postback of rblTest with this:

```
rblTest.Items[0].Text
```

and it just gives me the original value of it and not what i changed it to.
So maybe its just not possible to change text via client and only possible via server sided code... or is it? Maybe one of u got some ideas... Any suggiestions or thoughts could help :)

thx in advance :-)

Comment: $('#rblTest_0').text("inputchanged"); ?

Comment: yes to change the value of the first radiobuttonlistitem. this works and it does change that... the text inputchanged it just as test... but then when postback it does not see the change... :-( maybe not possible to change radiobuttonlist with jquery and get the TextChanged fired... :-(... or is it?

Comment: I've been playing with it, I think you might have to get to your code behind directly through jquery/ajax. One moment and I should have a working piece of code for you. edit: the approach I was taking didn't pan out. Still looking.

Comment: oh :( but thx for trying :-) well i guess i could make a whole other system in jquery to check is some of the texts is changed... it would just be smarter to use the TextChanged method now that its there... Also because when i need to see if something is changed its because i have to save it to a database. so even more sense u use TextChanged

Comment: yea sorry, it looks like it's time to investigate workarounds. :(

Comment: yes that may be true... would still like to hear if someone have experienced something like this particular problem or any thoughts in that matter :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to simulate user's click on your rbs.
Something like that

$('#rb').trigger('click');

[More about "trigger".](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Please note, rb - is your radio button () element and not a label.

Comment: well this doesnt seem to do it... are you sure you didnt mean selectedindex changed? because it still does not fire the textchanged event. and trying to return rblTest.Items[0].Text still returns the old value and not the changed value that i changed via jquery.